# How to get inner child's data in Firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I get the comment ID that start with `"comments_"`?

```
String ref = holder.reference
  .child(postModelArrayList.get(position).getUserId())
  .child(postModelArrayList.get(position).getPostId())
  .getKey();

Toast.makeText(mContext, ""+ref, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

[image: My user post database structure]

Comment: Your code is not reading anything from the database yet. I recommend reading the Firebase documentation for some good examples of how to do that: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once

Answer (score 0):

To get all children that start with `"Comments_"`, you'll need to perform a query for it:

```java
holder.reference
  .child(postModelArrayList.get(position).getUserId())
  .child(postModelArrayList.get(position).getPostId())
  .startAt("Comments_")
  .endAt("Comments_\uf8ff")
  .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot querySnapshot) {
      for (DataSnapshot commentSnapshot: querySnapshot.getChildren()) {
        // this is a comment's data
        String key = commentSnapshot.key;
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
      // Getting comments failed, log a message
      Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
      // ...
    }
  });
```

This query is unnecessarily complex and also won't allow you to do things like get all comments made by a particular user.

I recommend restructuring your data to:

```json
"/Posts/{userId}": {
  "{postId}": {
    "comments": {
      // comments go here
      "{commentId}": { /* ... */ }
    },
    "data": {
      "Description": "",
      "Tag": "Add Tag",
      "postId": "20210401_010700",
      "postUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tra...",
      "userId": "xirXhPLK6GO13be58UBI87TAe4E2",
      "userDisplayName": "Furqan Shah" // reserve username for future use
    }
  }
}
```

If you just want the post's data (without the comments), use the reference:

```
/Posts/{userId}/{postId}/data
```

If you want a specific comment, use the reference:

```
/Posts/{userId}/{postId}/comments/{commentId}
```

If you want a post and ALL of it's comments, use the reference:

```
/Posts/{userId}/{postId}
```